# How to get notified in Firebase of email verification?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use Firebase Auth for email/password sign up. The problem is that I only want to accept the user as authenticated when the email address used is also verified.

Normally we can use a listener to check when a user is signed in or no longer signed in:

```
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
```

The issue is that this listener is not triggered when the user clicks on the link in the verification email. It's only called once the account is created.

Doing the following in a loop works while waiting for the user to click the link:

```
        Auth.auth().currentUser!.reload() {
            if !Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
```

but the problem is I ideally want to manage all the auth stuff in the listener callback, but the listener is not used when the email validation state changes.

Is there something I am missing?

I know on mobile you can use deep linking so the link in the mail would open the app again, but that's not what I am looking for as users could open the mail on their computer so the problem still needs to be solved.

For now the only solution I see is to send an nsnotification myself and handle it where I handle all the auth code, but it feels a bit messy.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some options:

1. Set
   up a RTDB node to track the `emailVerified` of a user.
2. Implement your own landing page for email verification: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler
3. In your landing page, when the user is verified, update `emailVerified` in that RTDB node.
4. On the page where the user sent the email verification, listen to changes on that node. On change, call `user.reload()` to update `emailVerified` on the user and `user.getIdToken(true)` to make sure the token is udpated with the latest claims.

Another way is a variation of the above which is to add a [`continueUrl`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions) which will show a continue button on the default email verification to redirect to a page you own where you know the user is verified. You can also use a similar mechanism as above to pass the status change via real-time database on that page instead of the landing page.

Comment: That's basically a more complicated variation of what I did by just polling the state every second. There is no way to have the listener trigger it seems.

Comment: Polling is an inefficient and expensive solution. This is the whole point of using realtime database, to avoid polling based notification systems especially on mobile devices.

Comment: TBH I don't really care about the efficiency in this case. It only happens at first signup or when a user changes an email address. If the system can't cope the load of checking once a second if something has changed when doing this there are bigger problems to tackle. It's not as if this is running constantly in the background for the entire lifetime of the app.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but that doesn't change the fact that polling is inefficient. Email verification is not guaranteed to happen instantaneously or immediately after sign up. In some cases, the flow may even be abandoned by the user. So you'll be polling for a long time. This is the recommended solution from Firebase.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated. Firebase auto logs-in unverified users. Other websites and apps handle this by limiting the user's ability in the app. I think this is what we should do in this case. But even that is complicated because you have to basically design multiple states for your app.

Comment: But what if the user who is supposed to verify their email closes that page? Then the changes won't be 'heard' and no database status update will happen. How to handle this situation? 
I need this to implement auto login that is supposed to be triggered after the user has verified his or her email.

Comment: @boleil I need help trying to implement your suggestions, particularly the one in step 3. I think what you meant is to update the RTDB node to say that the email address has already been verified via the custom email action handler web app. The problem though is the user is not authenticated in this web app and my RTDB restricts read and write access to authenticated users. How do I make the RTDB update if this is the case?

Comment: @zepolyerf setup a separate node for email verifications only and setup the firebase rules to allow read/write on that node without authentication. That could be one of the way.